# Flutter align widget to centre and another to the right - impossible

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

I'm trying to do something which should be extremely simple but can't see how it is done.

I need to align the large text to the centre and the buttons to the right so it looks like image below:

[image]

With the code below the widgets are aligned left and right:

```
    Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colour.darkBlue, width: 2),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(100, 60)),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Centred', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32)),
              Text('24.6 %', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 48)),
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('BtnA', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                Text('BtnB', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                Text('BtnC', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

I tried the following method:

```
    Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colour.darkBlue, width: 2),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(100, 60)),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Container()),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Centred', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32)),
                Text('24.6 %', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 48)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('BtnA', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                  Text('BtnB', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                  Text('BtnC', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

But it resulted in this:

[image]

> Not sure how or whether it can be done without manually setting a width for the container on the left which is clearly a far from ideal method. Flutter seems to desperately need `float:right`...

Comment: Have you tried used `SizedBox` on Left side(empty) and Right side? Both set the `width` and Expand the middle `Column`, Or try to set `flex` factor as [official's youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=38&v=_rnZaagadyo)

Comment: @Tokenyet Isn't that effectively the same as what I listed as I tried already? The second block of code.

Comment: @Tokenyet The main problem is how to actually centre the big text so it's *really* centred. Seems to be something flutter struggles with. It relies too much on the position of all the other elements around it, so here with only one element on the right, it doesn't know how to centre it.

Answer (score 1):

You was almost there. Just "Expanded" in the middle should be removed:

```
    Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 2),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(100, 60)),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(child: Container()),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Centred', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32)),
              Text('24.6 %', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 48)),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('BtnA', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                  Text('BtnB', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                  Text('BtnC', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with ListTile Widget, I have made changes using ListTile, please check if it works for you

[image]

```
 Center(
    child: Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      width: 300,
      height: 150,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 2),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(100, 60)),
      ),
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text('Centred',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
        subtitle: Text('24.6 %',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 48)),
        trailing: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('BtnA', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
            Text('BtnB', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
            Text('BtnC', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Great answer bro!

Comment: Doesn't work at all. Why didn't you check it first? The big text is on the left and the ListTile is on the right.

Comment: Even your image shows it DOESN'T work...?? How is the big text in the centre of the ellipse there??

Comment: How does that look like the first image in my question??

Comment: Why does it work? It's still not in the centre in your image.

Comment: I'm talking about horizontal centreing, like in my image in the question.

Comment: It just looks more central because it's wider than the buttons on the right. But it's still clearly off to the left, it's not centred. Try making the buttons on the right larger and you'll see they're just panned left and right. There's no actual alignment going on here.

Comment: You should just delete your answer I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
    child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 300,
            height: 150,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(100, 60)),
            ),
            child: Container(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Flexible(
                            child: Text('Centred',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32)),
                          ),
                          Flexible(
                            child: Text('24.6 %',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 48)),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('BtnA', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                          Text('BtnB', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                          Text('BtnC', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: Yes may be not clear, explain what you actually want in center?

Comment: Please delete your answer. The large text is even CALLED 'Centred'! I don't see how you can not know which text needed to be centred...

Comment: @Hasen have you check it ?